# Creating clustered primary key index takes a very long time in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, azure-sql-database

I have a table with millions of records and it is taking a very long time to create the clustered index on its primary key.

What are the factors required in consideration to faster the process to creating PK clustered on it?

I have triggers, views, non-clustered indexes, foreign keys and some auto created statistics & statistics on non-clustered indexes.

Comment: You can drop all the non clustered indexes on it first, then create the clustered index, then crreate the non clustered index. It might be faster. This is an I/O (disk speed) heavy operation.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - yes i am doing the same but still it is taking 4 hours

Comment: Remember that (a) nonclustered indexes are a separate data structure than the table rows, whereas (b) clustered indexes are not a separate data structure - they are the actual rows of the table. This is why you can only have one clustered index per table. It's taking a long time to add a clustered index because it's actually reordering the rows of the table on storage to match the index keys. The larger the table the longer it takes. The more complex the index (e.g.: composite keys) the longer it takes. The slower the underlying storage (magnetic hard disks versus SSDs) the longer it takes.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - agree.

Comment: It's a good opportuntiy to take a look at task manager > performance and see what is busiest - CPU, RAM, or disks.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - i was thinking to look at wait type in dm_exec_requests to identify what resource is waiting for i addition to task manager

Comment: For sure you should definitely do that. `sp_whoisactive` is an excellent tool for showing that info. I think basically it will simply say buffer IO

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I had a look on wait type and obseved that PAGEIOLATCH_EX , PAGEIOLATCH_UP & CXPACKET wait types also when had a look in dm_os_waiting_tasks observed blocking at internal threads also sp_locks shows ENCRYPTED_SCAN at db level but my db is not TDE enabled still showing this. any sugguessions here ?

Comment: Another thing to note is that you're reading and writing to the same `file` which leads to bad IO performance. Recreating the table on a different file, on a different disk, is probably a way to speed things up

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

- Create a new table
- Create a clustered index for it
- Create the trigger and disable them
- Copy all data from the old table to the new table
- Finally, do the following:

  ```
  sp_rename '<Current_old_Table>',<Current_old_Table_BAK>'
  sp_rename '<New_Table>',<Current_Table_BAK>'
  ```

Comment: Did you miss some opening and closing `'` ?